# How can I tell Emacs to correctly fill around Latex comments

Tags: emacs, comments

When I edit a .tex file in emacs, I frequently use fill-paragraph. Comments indicated with '%' sometimes wrap correctly, and sometimes they do not. It is not clear to me what is making this fail.

Example:

```
% This is a comment
This is a very very very long line of very very very long text
```

When I run fill-paragraph, I sometimes get the undesirable:

```
% This is a comment This is a very very 
very long line of very very very long text
```

I'm using Emacs 23.1.1 in Latex-mode, and the following minor modes are enabled:

```
Enabled minor modes: Abbrev Auto-Composition Auto-Compression
Auto-Encryption Auto-Fill Display-Time File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock
Global-Auto-Composition Global-Font-Lock Iswitchb Line-Number Outline
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren
```

Comment: Without a precise recipe to reproduce the problem it's hard to help you.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me.

Comment: Doesn't happen to me either, although I find wrapping text near comments sometimes behaves 'incorrectly' when using `TeX-mode`.  Are you sure you're in `LaTeX-mode`?  And do you have AUCTeX installed?

Comment: jon, I've just installed AUCTex (hadn't heard of it before), and commenting works correctly and everything looks much better. Thanks!

Comment: What's the protocol - should I copy jon's comment into the answer and accept it, or should the question be deleted on account of being trivial / insufficiently specific?

Comment: @jon, see above

Comment: AUCTeX (and RefTeX) is great!  As for the protocol, I'm pretty sure there must be discussion on the meta site.  I think the best thing is either to close to question or get it answered somehow.  I can try to find time this weekend to post a slightly more verbose answer, unless it gets closed in the meantime.

Comment: @jon Doesn't have to be that verbose—maybe just a confirmation that the problems happens with `TeX-mode` and not `LaTeX-mode` :-)  (Which, by the way, is not the case for me… `TeX-mode` works fine.  It's possible the bug was fixed.)

Comment: Also on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945040/possible-to-get-emacs-to-ignore-comments-during-paragraph-fill-in-latex-mode/62538476#62538476

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Just to take the question off the unanswered list.)

I find this behaviour --- i.e., incorrect line-wrapping near comments via `M-x fill-paragraph` or `M-q` --- *sometimes* occurs when using Emacs in `TeX-mode`.  With `LaTeX-mode`, I have not experienced this problem.  With AUCTeX the situation is still improved, and this is one of the least important reasons to use AUCTeX. (Anyway, for more information on modes, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Modes-and-Hooks).)

If Emacs is guessing the 'wrong' mode for your file, you can help it by setting the local variables.  This can be done with a simple

```
% -*- mode: latex -*-
```

at the top of the file.  A preferred method, however, is to use the `Local Variables` block at/near the end of the file:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex   
%%% TeX-master: t   
%%% End:
```

I like this better because you can set other options at the same time; e.g.,

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex   
%%% TeX-master: t   
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% mode: flyspell
%%% End:
```

Comment: I am using `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)` which still generates the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For GNU Emacs, this bug has been [reported](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=38152) by Michael Orlitzky, who submitted the following patch which will be included in Emacs 27.1:

```
--- a/tex-mode.el   2019-01-07 09:26:07.000000000 -0500
+++ b/tex-mode.el   2019-11-09 08:42:56.649424361 -0500
@@ -1155,7 +1155,7 @@
        "\\>\\|\\\\[a-z]*" (regexp-opt '("space" "skip" "page") t)
        "\\>\\)"))
   (setq paragraph-separate
-   (concat "[\f%]\\|[ \t]*\\($\\|"
+   (concat "\\([ \t]*%\\)\\|[\f]\\|[ \t]*\\($\\|"
        "\\\\[][]\\|"
```

The patch fixes some cases but not all.  For instance the bug still occurs if you have a comment at the end of a line of code, followed by another line of code.  I've [reported](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=42016) this as well and will edit this answer with any updates.